# iOS7 Global Tint not affecting UIToolbar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios7

I'm finding some situations where the `Global Tint` I have set in the `MainStoryboard` isn't propagating to some sub `UIViews`.

An example case is simply to start with a 'MasterDetail' template application and show the `UIToolbar` in the `MasterViewController` by adding:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Any items I add to the toolbar appear in the system default tint rather than my custom Global Tint.

Is anyone else having issues with this? Has anyone found a fix?
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround.

Set the 'global tint' in code by setting the tint of the `UIWindow` and things work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[[application windows] lastObject] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    return YES;
}
```

So despite the Apple documentation saying that the Global Tint setting is for the entire App, there's clearly an issue with that and you need to set it in code on the `UIWindow`.

Comment: It's better to get the window using [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] (or just self.window, if called from within the app delegate). UIAlertViews have their own window, so you don't know what [[application windows] lastObject] might be if an alert pops up at the wrong moment.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to work on toolbars for some reason, I'm facing the same issue.

However, you can change the appearance (background not tini for some reason) of all uitoolbars from your AppDelegate, it works like charm.

Good luck, need any more help, let me know ;D

Comment: Thanks, although I don't want to change the background.